# Can something break under your weight whether you stand on it or hang under it?

Tags: grammar, questions

Can something break under your weight whether you stand on it or hang under it?

Does this example make sense:

The man tried to hang himself, but apparently the beam he had tied the rope around broke under his weight.

?

Answer (score 3):

Yes. The "under" doesn't imply an actual direction. It would also work for sideways motion:

> He tried to drag the boulder off the road with his truck, but the rope snapped under the strain.