# What would the natural tense be here?

Tags: tense, sequence-of-tenses

> **A:** *He tried to hang himself in his basement about a month ago.*
> **B:** *What?*
> **A:** *Yeah. Luckily the pipes ______(1) tied the rope to __________(2) under his weight, so nothing happened.*

Which of these would you insert in the dialog for it to be natural?

> (1) he / he'd
> (2) broke / had broken

For me, it would make sense to use **'he'd'** as he had tied the the rope before it broke. And for the second, I would guess that **'broke'** would be enough.

Comment: It's a good idea to write why you think an answer is best. So say "I think it should be "..." because ....."   This way we can answer your question about English, rather than just doing an exercise for you.

Comment: By the way.  Who writes grammar exercises about suicide attempts!?  There are lots of ways to learn about the past perfect without this.  Its not the first (unrelated) question like this https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/267068/can-something-break-under-your-weight-whether-you-stand-on-it-or-hang-under-it

Comment: It's an example from a story I'm writing, but maybe I should have made up another example if it's too inappropriate.

Comment: @JamesK one who wants to make grammar exercises more fun? :)

Comment: I would agree with your opinion, Bibobabu.

Comment: It sounds like (1) he tied the rope, (2) he tried to hang himself, and (3) the pipe broke. So the tying, and not the breaking, was already in the past at time (2). So I would say "The pipe he had tied the rope to broke under his weight." This is still not a very graceful sentence, because of the placement of the word "to," but I think that it puts the verbs in the correct tenses.

Comment: @Chaim that's what I've written in my answer

Comment: for me the first action is that he wanted to kill himself then he tied and at last the pipes broke. That is why I say that you don't need past perfect because all events are in chronological order . I really think that what came first was the idea of committing suicide and then how to do it

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, for the first one, it is correct to use **'he'd'** since he **had tied** the rope first.
But the second blank's a little confusing. I've studied that the word **'to'** is always followed by the *'base/root form'* of the verb. What I guess is that, **'to'** is not really required because if it's there then both of your options would be wrong.

Or did you mean like this:

> Luckily, the pipes ______(1) tied the rope to **,** __________(2) under his weight, so nothing happened.

If that's what you meant then your choice is right i.e., **'broke'** will do it. Like this:

> Luckily, the pipes **he'd** tied the rope to, **broke** under his weight, so nothing happened.

Comment: you are not obliged to use past perfect as the first action is tying then breaking comes after

Comment: No, we should use past perfect for the first action and simple past for the second. See [this](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/past-perfect/)

Comment: The "to" here is not related to "broke".  It's part of "tied to", not part of "to break".  So you're all right with using "broke".